# Null Pointer Exception on ListView Dialog

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, customdialog

I tried to make a custom simple listView dialog using onClick on editText. but it keep crashing, and logcat mention java null pointer exception on my setAdapter.

here's my code

```
kadarInput.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_listview_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Kadar Emas");

            ArrayList<String> kadarList = new ArrayList<String>();
            kadarList.addAll( Arrays.asList(kadar) );

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayItem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, kadarList);

            ListView kadarListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kadar_list);

            kadarListView.setAdapter(arrayItem);
            kadarListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    kadarInput.setText(kadarEmas[position]);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

and here's the custom dialog xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/kadar_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

could you guys tell me where did it went wrong?
any help will be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Use `ListView kadarListView = (ListView) dialog. findViewById(R.id.kadar_list` if ListView is inside `Dialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your ListView inside Dialog. So,

Instead of

```
ListView kadarListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kadar_list);
```

Use

```
ListView kadarListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.kadar_list);
```